# Which interface to choose SPI MIPI or Parallel?

Tags: spi, camera, high-speed, parallel-port, csi

I'm trying to connect the AR sensor module (AR0331) with the IMX6 processor and the problem is the camera uses a HiSPI & parallel line. Similarly, there is MI-PI (CSI) and Parallel line in the IMX6.
Which interface will work best if i want to get the best of the camera....
Parallel???
OR 
Serial??
and i want to use it for image processing so i want to make use of the camera to the fullest..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest you to use parallel interface port for better speed.For SPI based camera's it'll be slow when compared to parallel interface because of clock pulse used in the SPI.

  And moreover,parallel interface is straight forward but requires lots of pins for communication.But in the case of SPI,you just need 4 pins only(I dont know your camera's actual I/O present in SPI camera.But generally minimum of 4 pins require for SPI interface).

  If you want to save lot of your I/O in micro-controller,use SPI interface,but they are somehow slow(I didn't mean it's dead slow,just a little bit).If you don't worry about number of I/O pins ,you can use parallel interface.

Comment: Are you going to save the picture  using a SD card?.Because,for SD card,it uses SPI interface( there is also another interface in SD card,but for us,it's easy in SPI).So If you're using a SD card,the camera's SPI protocol and SD card's protocol will differ.So better to use parallel interface